# Do I have to submit my high school transcript if "transcripts for all current and previous post-secondary study" are required?

Tags: phd, canada, transcript-of-records

I want to apply for a PhD in Canada. The webpage of the university says that I have to submit "transcripts for all current and previous post-secondary study". Does that include high school transcripts?

Comment: Isn't "secondary" equivalent to "high school"?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin  No, secondary also includes grades 6 through 8.  Grades 7 and 8 and sometimes 9 are junior high.

Comment: [Education in Canada: Post-secondary](https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/new-immigrants/new-life-canada/education/types-school/post-secondary.html).  Research is a skill you will need to be successful in a PhD.  Don't miss an opportunity to practice.

Comment: Where do you live in Canada.  In Quebec, high schools are obviously "secondary" (the grades are _secondaire 1_ through _secondaire 5_).  My sister when to _SomethingOrOther Secondary School_ when she was in high school near Toronto.  _Post Secondary_ always meant _after high school_ everywhere I've lived (Quebec, Nova Scotia, Rhode Island and Texas)

Comment: @NicoleHamilton Thanks and "… secondary also includes grades 6 through 8. Grades 7 and 8… are junior high…" reads as clear as mud, here thickened by the unstated implication that "high school" means only "senior…" and not "junior high." Sorry to point this out, and your Answer below is equally dependant on prior knowledge, particularly in the strange claim that "Canada should be similar…" which, why?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin: Without further specification, in North America, "high school" always means high school, and never junior high. High school is the last four (or rarely, three) years before you become an undergrad (assuming you continue in your education). Junior high is a weird in-between level that comes after middle school and before high school, and it has been abolished in some places (with most or all of the grades folded into middle school).

Comment: @Kevin Sorry to have dragged us off topic. I that "always" is true, it still says nothing about any comparison with Canada. Luckily, what "high school" specifically means doesn't change its relationship to "secondary."

Answer (score 63, accepted):

No. Secondary refers to grades 7 through 12 in the US; Canada should be similar.  It's called secondary because it comes after the primary grades K through 6.  Junior high is usually grades 7 and 8.  High school is typically grades 9 through 12, so post-secondary is after high school, meaning college and graduate school and any vocational or certification training.

Comment: Also trade schools, IT certification courses, etc. "Post-secondary  education" covers more things than just university.

Comment: Though I doubt that a school would be interested in most kinds of vocational or certification training.  I certainly never had to submit a copy of my pilot's or commercial driver's licenses, for instance.

Comment: @jamesqf  Agree. But you might put them on your CV, where you can do whatever you like.  I mention I've been an bicycle rider all my life and have a ham license I haven't used in years on mine.  I don't think it ever got me a job but it might help readers get a better picture of who I am.

Comment: @jamesqf Sure, but if you have a certification as an aircraft maintenance engineer or plumber, it might be relevant if you're applying for an aviation- or water infrastructure-related PhD, for instance. If you're a Cisco-Certified Network Associate, that might be relevant to a PhD in communications networks.

Comment: I think it's called secondary because prior to the 20th century, high school was intended only for those going to college (hence "prep school") and so attendance was not common, compulsory, nor publicly funded. Only a primary education was mandatory and free.

Comment: @user71659 That's very unlikely. Prior to the recent times it was actually much more common to finish your education with a sort of high school. And not just a general one like grammar schools/gymnasiums but also those oriented at acounting, agriculture, forestry and many other areas of economy. Then there was the very important vocational training. A MUCH more important section of education thatn it is now, And then unskilled workers who only had the elementary/primary school. University education was only available to a small part of the population.

Comment: Minor quibble: Primary usually goes further than 5th grade in the US.  Secondary is very commonly used to mean only 9th and up; sometimes it includes back as far as seventh, but I don't think I'd ever see 6th grade as "secondary" (and until relatively recently it was in the same school as K-5 in most places in the US).  It's still very common to have K-8 schools (my kids go to one, a public school).

Comment: @Joe I struggled with that too but went with [Wikipedia's definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secondary_education_in_the_United_States) but I think you're right.  Your experience matches mine growing up.  So, I'm going to change it.

Comment: @VladimirF I don't know about Europe, but in the rural US it was unusual to attend any sort of secondary school until the 20th century. Vocational training was primarily at home.  Both high-school and post-secondary education were rare.

Comment: @VladimirF It's not just the US. It was actually [determined in the UK in 1899](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cockerton_Judgement) that public schools over the age of 12 were illegal. Only after it was [fixed a few years later](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Education_Act_1902) did high schools become common.

Comment: @BryanKrause Vocational training usually happened in individual shops or workshops, but was nevertheless extremely important. However, I DID NOT claim that there were that many secondary school student. What I DID claim is that most of those that were there did not study university. Notably, for many skilled non-manual professions a high school was good enough back then. Alas, even in the early 2000s many of my schoolmates found a good without one, while with Bologna everyone now pursues some kind of Bc.

Comment: @user71659 Austria (half of Austria-Hungary) had obligatory 9 years in 1869 arleady. Obligatory elementary education already came in the 18th century. There were many public secondary schools. The gymnasium I attended started in 1833 as a realgymnasium.

Comment: @BryanKrause But I really had in mind those specialized secondary schools that were already preparing for a certain kind of job. Businnes academies (Handelsakademie], forestry schools, agricultural schools, even a specialized wine and fruit school (yes, Mělník 1885). Polytechnical ones. Military ones. There were countless of these and there is no point to list all the professions and subjects of economy that need people with secondary education. Most of the graduates went to their jobs, NOT to a university.

Answer (score 15):

No. Post secondary is undergraduate and beyond

Comment: It can be _less than undergraduate_ as well.  Quebec (a province in Canada (where the OP is asking about)) has a system of post-secondary colleges (CEGEPs) that provide either pre-university or technical diplomas.  They are considered post-secondary institutions.  US community colleges are similar (though they describe their diplomas as "Associate Degrees".  I've never heard of either types of colleges referred to as _undergraduate education_

Answer (score 2):

While your high school studies count as secondary study, if you did AP classes (especially if you used them towards your degree) or vocational classes that gave some kind of trade certificate (especially higher level ones) they are "post-secondary" even though you did them before finishing secondary study, so the university probably wants them officially documented.